# Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean

Tags: visualforce

Can any one let me know why do i get this Error as :

```
Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean .
```

Im trying to Compare the Product Name with the Quantity and Amount.If the Quantity and Amount has the same Product name ,it should get displayed only once with the Quantity and Amount added.

error occurs on this line:

```
   w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
```

Here is my code...

```
if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name)){

                               w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);

                               w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                               w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod_Amount__c;

                  } else {

                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;


    }
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: line in error? ....

Comment: @ crop1645: I get Error at this line :w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;If i comment this line : i gives the Error at another line : w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod_Amount__c;

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have the fields you are trying to extract defined incorrectly.
`.gmod_Quantity` should probably be `.gmod_Quantity__c`

and same for `.gmod_Amount`

So it would look like this:

```
if (disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name)) {

w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);

w.gmod_Quantity = disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity__c + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount__c + opflist[i].gmod_Amount__c;

 } else {

w.gmod_Quantity = opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

w.gmod_Amount = opflist[i].gmod__Amount__c;


}
```

Comment: :gmod_Quantity,gmod_Amount are wrapper varibles in class

Comment: you can have glance at this link :http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66697/how-to-create-a-table-without-repeating-the-same-name-non-grouped-column-data-in/66727?noredirect=1#comment87430_66727.Where i have posted with my sceanrio.Any help is very much appreciated.